# Access denied on publish via ftp but works fine on publish to local IIS (.NET Application)

Tags: asp.net, iis, ftp

Soo.. I'm trying to help a friend build up hes photo-gallery-site.. Everything works just fine until i was about to publish it..

So to start of.. The first issue when i'm trying to push it up (VIA FTP - To citynetwork (webhost), i got:

```
Parser Error Message: The 'targetFramework' attribute in the <compilation> element of the Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example, '<compilation targetFramework="4.0">'). The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework.
```

I've solved that to just change:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
```

To:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

But then i get another wierd error that looks something like this:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied - Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "\\webstorage\storage_content\00\102600\elliotelliot.com\public_html\bin\roslyn\csc.exe"
```

Please help mee. I'm soooooo confused, i mean.. It works just fine when im publishing it to my local iis server and run it from there, all the files is also pushed up (nothing missing), anyone else with this issue?

I've seen people talk about application pools and users (therefore the "Access is denied" state)

Thanks!
/R

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Why **`csc.exe`** is pointing to some other location than the framework location.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to an issue I faced. I fixed it by changing the .NET Target version to 4.5. I changed it through Visual Studio instead of directly editing the web.config file, I don't know if this would make a difference or not.

There's more information, and more things to try in [this article](http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/07/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception.html).
Hopefully something there helps.